# How to convert land zoned as Agricultural to Residential in Massachusetts

Tags: united-states, real-estate, massachusetts, land

How can I convert a multi acre land, termed currently as "Zone Usage: Single Family/Agriculture" in central Massachusetts, into smaller residential pieces. What all are the procedures, dues, fees, expected time etc for the entire process.

Comment: This question is not really about personal finance except in a very peripheral way.

Comment: Call your local zoning board.

Answer (score 2):

All zoning is local. The exact procure for making a minor change or a major change is detailed at the local level. And by local that could be county/city/town.

> From: Single Family/Agriculture" ... into smaller residential pieces.

Depending on the zoning documents for your jurisdiction that could either be a small change or a large change.

Small changes involve design drawings, paperwork and a small hearing: total time a few months. Costs include government fees and the cost associated with the development of the design and the cost of a land use attorney.

Large changes may involve design drawings, paperwork, multiple hearings in front of multiple boards, a public comment period, a change in regulation that has to be voted on my the local government and could take years. Costs much larger, because if the committee involved in road use finds a major issue, then the process might have to start over. Time to complete years, or it could get rejected.

See a local land use attorney for advice.

Comment: costs: And likely a land surveyor to draw up the plats for the subdivision. A land surveyor who's done this before may also be helping in navigating the zoning, etc.